# accessing php variables in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation

what i am trying to achieve is basically mark the location of all the users logged into my chat which is another thing. so i though i'd use geolocation api (http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) and store the generated location in a session variable. but its not working. here is the code-`

```
<?php 
    $my_lat= $_GET['test'];             // get data
    $my_long= $_GET['fname']; 
    $my_name = "vivek";
    $lat1=28.635308;
    $long1=77.22496;
    //$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
    //$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];// get data
    echo $my_lat.''.$my_long;
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=''
&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var longi= position.coords.longitude;
            var  url = 'bam.php';
        //post to the server!
        $.get(url, { test: lat,fname: longi },function(data){
        alert('data was passed!');
        });


          }, function() {
            //now is when the marking should be done.
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });

  }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.635308,77.22496);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var thelat = '<?php echo $my_lat;?>';
    var thelong = '<?php echo $my_long;?>';
    var seslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(thelat,thelong);
    alert(seslatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: seslatlng, 
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello world!",
    }); 



}

</script>`
```

and the problem is. that the variable seslatlng is set to (0,0) always which is not what i want. i am new to PHP and i only have rough idea how server side scripting works. can somebody please fix this?

Comment: 1) What do you get when you run  echo $my_lat.''.$my_long? 2) Why do you set the center of the map to a hard-coded value instead of centering it based on client's IP location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you are setting seslatlng. If you're wanting this to be a JS variable, add:

```
var seslatlng = "(<?php echo $my_lat . ',' . $my_lng; ?>)"; // (30.230, 8.030)
```

Comment: i assign seslatng using var thelat and thelong. here is the code-        varthelat = '<?php echo $my_lat;?>';
var thelong = '<?php echo $my_long;?>';
var seslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(thelat,thelong);

Comment: i used the code u gave me and it doesn't seem to work with $my_lat and $my_lng may be coz it is parsed from the server or something. but it works well the variables $lat1 and $long1 whose value the server already knows. the thing is the php part of the code is compiled much before the client sees anything in the browser. i don't know how to fix it. i am new to this. any help will be greatly   appreciated! thnx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using  and  for assigning values to javascript variables, use:

```
var thelat = '<?=$my_lat?>';
var thelong = '<?=$my_long?>';
```

and it will work for you. I have also tried it to assign php variables value to javascript variables.

Comment: This is semantically identical to `<?php echo $my_long;?>` except this version requires `short_open_tag` to be enabled before PHP/5.4, which it rarely is in production environments.

Comment: And remember to escape strings when needed! I use this function: http://codepad.org/QOTeP3FY. In this case you have numerics, so theoretically you don't need it.

Comment: @Rajat the code i am using works perfectly and so does yours but its pointing to (0,0). i do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using jquery's ajax get function, what you wanna do is call a php function that **only** returns the locations. this is how is should look:

```
<?php 

    if ( $_GET['test'] ) {
        $my_lat= $_GET['test'];             // get data
        $my_long= $_GET['fname']; 
        $my_name = "vivek";
        $lat1=28.635308;
        $long1=77.22496;
        //$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
        //$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];// get data
        echo $my_lat.''.$my_long;
    } else {
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=''
&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.geolocation) {

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var longi= position.coords.longitude;
            var  url = 'bam.php';
        //post to the server!
        $.get(url, { test: lat,fname: longi },function(data){
        alert('My location is: ' + data);
        });


          }, function() {
            //now is when the marking should be done.
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });

  }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.635308,77.22496);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var thelat = '<?php echo $my_lat;?>';
    var thelong = '<?php echo $my_long;?>';
    var seslatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(thelat,thelong);
    alert(seslatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: seslatlng, 
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello world!"
    }); 



}

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: but i wana use the locations returned. did u try running the code u just gave me. u will have to explain. it doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
</script>
```

Purpose of json_encode is to escpe the quotes and other entities `<?php echo $a; ?>` can break your code.